# Android - Open Music Player

Tags: android

Is there any way to programatically open the Android Music Player?

I'm sure there is some kind of Intent somewhere but I cannot find it.

James

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`android.intent.action.MUSIC_PLAYER` is your friend. See [MediaStore on Android Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html) for further information.

Answer (score 7):

Create a new intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MUSIC_PLAYER");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: It is not working for me. My target platform is 8. Please let me know, if you need any additional information.. Please refer this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14106494/android-launch-music-player-via-service that I am looking for some help, please help me...

Answer (score 4):

Since API level 15:
action="android.intent.action.MAIN"
category="android.intent.category.APP_MUSIC"

Answer (score -1):

since api 15 android.intent.action.MUSIC_PLAYER is deprecated try this code

```
try {
                String pkgname = "com.sec.android.app.music";
                PackageManager pkgmanager = getPackageManager();
                Intent intent = pkgmanager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(pkgname);
                startActivity(intent);
            } catch(Exception e) {
                // music player not found
            }
```

add this code on your on click listener and this will open the default music player