# Android : Launch Music Player via Service

Tags: android, android-music-player

I am trying to launch the MediaPlayer from a service, and its not wroking as expected. I m getting the following exception,

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.MUSIC_PLAYER flg=0x10000000 }
```

Please find the snippet of code that gets invoked in the service,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_MUSIC_PLAYER);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Android Manifest

```
<service android:name="com.lakshmi.shakenfun.AlertService" >
    <intent-filter >
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MUSIC_PLAYER" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Please do let me know, where I am doing wrong.

My target platform is 8

Thanks,
Ramesh

Comment: You can't start a `Service` using `startActivity(intent);`. To start a `Service` you use `startService(...)`.

Comment: Are you trying to start the device's media player? If so, why do you have the `MEDIA_PLAYER` action defined on an `<intent-filter>` of your own service? With respect to the error, apparently there is no activity on your device or emulator that supports that particular `Intent` action.

Comment: I need to launch a media player from a service. I don't want to start a service. I referred this link to launch a media player from my service,

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3114471/android-launching-music-player-using-intent

To simply launch the music player do:

Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_MUSIC_PLAYER);
startActivity(intent);

Comment: I wanted to open the Media player by default and play the first song by default. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps your Target Platform of 8 is too low for that api?   Do you have this music player loaded?  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.music&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEsImNvbS5nb29nbGUuYW5kcm9pZC5tdXNpYyJd

Comment: You are right. I don't have this music player but after installing this app, the above code is working fine. But how to launch any music app without installing this particular app?

Answer (score 1):

MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_MUSIC_PLAYER is deprecated from API 15 the new code is:

```
try {
    String pkgname = "com.sec.android.app.music";
    PackageManager pkgmanager = getPackageManager();
    Intent intent = pkgmanager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(pkgname);
    startActivity(intent);
} catch(Exception e) {
    // music player not found
}
```

Just add this code on your button listener and it will call the default music player.